# Does Apple review entreprise apps?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I think I have a great idea for an iOS development tool, but I know apple will not allow it on the App Store.
My only solution is enterprise distribution, but does apple also review these apps ? Can apple block me if I distribute a private app that they don't "like" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they won't review them.

You can distribuite applications with the so-called *in-house* distribution that you just do privately..